# Eclipse arm pluging missing hal pack

Tags: stm32, eclipse, hal-library

I am trying to use Eclipse ARM plugin but it seems that there is no HAL library support for anything other then stm32f4.

Is it possible to add support for stm32f1 somehow.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is to download [STM32CubeF1](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/LN1897/PF260820?icmp=pf260820_pron_pr_feb2015&sc=stm32cubef1-pr). It contains all the HAL drivers that you're looking for. It also includes code examples and possibly some project files you can import directly into Eclipse.

Comment: +1, In addition, here is a [description](http://www.carminenoviello.com/en/2015/06/04/stm32-applications-eclipse-gcc-stcube/) about how to import properly HAL lib into Eclipse when using other than STM32F4.